# Не могу получить параметр из текущего URL

Tags: javascript, url, get

Нужно получить параметр из текущего адреса (из адресной строки), изменить его и перейти по полученной ссылке.

В тестовом варианте, если вбить url руками, то всё работает.

```
var url = new URL('https://www.example.com/params?isItem=true&paramId=123');

var u = url.searchParams.get('paramId');  // тут всё ок, u = 123 и дальше его можно изменить и подставить через url.searchParams.set . Но мне нужно не один раз изменить 'paramId', а постоянно менять его и переходить по новым ссылкам.
```

Перехожу к проблеме. Если вбивать начальный URL не руками, а попытаться подхватить значение параметра из текущего url в браузерной строке, то получить значение параметра уже не получается. Выскакивает ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')"

```
var url = window.location.href;
alert(url); //тут видно, что url абсолютно такой же, как примере выше (https://www.example.com/params?isItem=true&paramId=123), но при этом url.searchParams.get не может подцепить значение 123, а выдаёт ошибку. Почему? И как можно исправить?
var u = url.searchParams.get('paramId');  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Comment: `window.location.href` возвращает строку, а не экзмп. объекта URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас записи не идентичны. У `location.href` нет метода `searchParams`, т.к. он возвращает строку, а не объект.

Вместо `url = window.location.href;`  пишите как выше `url = new URL(window.location.href);`

Однако помните, что если нет гет параметра с нужным ключом `url.searchParams.get('paramId');` всё равно вернёт `null`

Comment: То, что надо, спасибо! с url = new URL(window.location.href); всё работает.

Comment: Отлично!) Галочку тык %)

Answer (score 0):

Дело window.location.href возвращает строку у которой нет такого метода, чтобы получить нужный гет параметр можете воспользоваться `window.location.search`

```
const params = window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce((p,e) =>{
            const a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['paramId']); // Нужный вам параметр
```